# range between two dates with 50 years?

Tags: r

I want a sequence of two dates every 50 years between  2000/01/01   and 10000/01/01

I tried this, but don't know how to select every 50 years rather than every single year:

```
 gg = seq(as.Date("2000/01/01"), by = "year", length.out = 8001)
```

output

2000  2050 2100  2150 .....10000

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.Date.html

Comment: interesting - i tried to go up to "10000-01-01" but R (lubridate) won't let me. 

`seq(ymd("2000/01/01"), to = ymd("9999/01/01"), by="year") %>% .[year(.)%%50==0] ` this almost works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `"50 year"` in the `by =`  argument:

```r
seq(as.Date("2000/01/01"), by = "50 year", length.out = 161)
#>   [1] "2000-01-01"  "2050-01-01"  "2100-01-01"  "2150-01-01"  "2200-01-01" 
#>   [6] "2250-01-01"  "2300-01-01"  "2350-01-01"  "2400-01-01"  "2450-01-01" 
#>  [11] "2500-01-01"  "2550-01-01"  "2600-01-01"  "2650-01-01"  "2700-01-01" 
#>  [16] "2750-01-01"  "2800-01-01"  "2850-01-01"  "2900-01-01"  "2950-01-01" 
#>  [21] "3000-01-01"  "3050-01-01"  "3100-01-01"  "3150-01-01"  "3200-01-01" 
#>  [26] "3250-01-01"  "3300-01-01"  "3350-01-01"  "3400-01-01"  "3450-01-01" 
#>  [31] "3500-01-01"  "3550-01-01"  "3600-01-01"  "3650-01-01"  "3700-01-01" 
#>  [36] "3750-01-01"  "3800-01-01"  "3850-01-01"  "3900-01-01"  "3950-01-01" 
#>  [41] "4000-01-01"  "4050-01-01"  "4100-01-01"  "4150-01-01"  "4200-01-01" 
#>  [46] "4250-01-01"  "4300-01-01"  "4350-01-01"  "4400-01-01"  "4450-01-01" 
#>  [51] "4500-01-01"  "4550-01-01"  "4600-01-01"  "4650-01-01"  "4700-01-01" 
#>  [56] "4750-01-01"  "4800-01-01"  "4850-01-01"  "4900-01-01"  "4950-01-01" 
#>  [61] "5000-01-01"  "5050-01-01"  "5100-01-01"  "5150-01-01"  "5200-01-01" 
#>  [66] "5250-01-01"  "5300-01-01"  "5350-01-01"  "5400-01-01"  "5450-01-01" 
#>  [71] "5500-01-01"  "5550-01-01"  "5600-01-01"  "5650-01-01"  "5700-01-01" 
#>  [76] "5750-01-01"  "5800-01-01"  "5850-01-01"  "5900-01-01"  "5950-01-01" 
#>  [81] "6000-01-01"  "6050-01-01"  "6100-01-01"  "6150-01-01"  "6200-01-01" 
#>  [86] "6250-01-01"  "6300-01-01"  "6350-01-01"  "6400-01-01"  "6450-01-01" 
#>  [91] "6500-01-01"  "6550-01-01"  "6600-01-01"  "6650-01-01"  "6700-01-01" 
#>  [96] "6750-01-01"  "6800-01-01"  "6850-01-01"  "6900-01-01"  "6950-01-01" 
#> [101] "7000-01-01"  "7050-01-01"  "7100-01-01"  "7150-01-01"  "7200-01-01" 
#> [106] "7250-01-01"  "7300-01-01"  "7350-01-01"  "7400-01-01"  "7450-01-01" 
#> [111] "7500-01-01"  "7550-01-01"  "7600-01-01"  "7650-01-01"  "7700-01-01" 
#> [116] "7750-01-01"  "7800-01-01"  "7850-01-01"  "7900-01-01"  "7950-01-01" 
#> [121] "8000-01-01"  "8050-01-01"  "8100-01-01"  "8150-01-01"  "8200-01-01" 
#> [126] "8250-01-01"  "8300-01-01"  "8350-01-01"  "8400-01-01"  "8450-01-01" 
#> [131] "8500-01-01"  "8550-01-01"  "8600-01-01"  "8650-01-01"  "8700-01-01" 
#> [136] "8750-01-01"  "8800-01-01"  "8850-01-01"  "8900-01-01"  "8950-01-01" 
#> [141] "9000-01-01"  "9050-01-01"  "9100-01-01"  "9150-01-01"  "9200-01-01" 
#> [146] "9250-01-01"  "9300-01-01"  "9350-01-01"  "9400-01-01"  "9450-01-01" 
#> [151] "9500-01-01"  "9550-01-01"  "9600-01-01"  "9650-01-01"  "9700-01-01" 
#> [156] "9750-01-01"  "9800-01-01"  "9850-01-01"  "9900-01-01"  "9950-01-01" 
#> [161] "10000-01-01"
```

Comment: The interesting thing is you have to do this rather than doing `seq(from = as.Date("2000-01-01"), to = as.Date("10000-01-01"), by = "50 years")` because, as the [`strptime()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) docs note, _For input, only years 0:9999 are accepted_

Comment: @M-- I agree in the general case, but I couldn't find an exact duplicate on SO (where the solution is using integer multiples in the `by` argument). I don't have any problem with the question being closed as a duplicate if that's the case, but simply pointing to the docs in the comments isn't as useful as an answer. There are many questions on SO where the answer can be found in the docs, but they are still useful Q&As because folks will often use a search engine to get a direct answer rather than reading through all the docs.

Comment: Thanks, I need only  2000 2050 2100 etc (but still the class is as.date)

Comment: @temor in that case you can do `seq(2000, 10000, 50)`. But the output will be numeric. A date object in R _must_ have a day and a month, or it is not a date.